# Alexa Distribution Availability always points to all countries inspite of adding "isAvailableWorldwide": false

Tags: amazon-web-services, alexa-skills-kit, ask-cli

According to the alexa document the below values are set for skill distribution availability

[Alexa Skill Manifest Link](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/smapi/skill-manifest.html)

```
"isAvailableWorldwide": false,                                    
"distributionCountries": [
    "US",
    "CA",
    "AU"
  ]
```

But still alexa always points to "all the countries" when ask-cli deployment is done.
Noticed this behaviour recently and earlier it was working fine , and nothing is changed in "skill.json"

Is anything missing in-order to make the distribution available only in specific countries?[AlexaSkill->Distribution->Availability](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BqSTk.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have to add distributionMode field in-order to select the distributionCountries after the ask-cli update.

```
"distributionMode": "PUBLIC"
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything wrong in the snippet you provided. In order to narrow down the problem I would edit the description in skill.json to force a change with the next deployment that you could check in the Alexa developer console. Based on the outcome you could check your tool chain or contact Alexa developer support if it's a bug.

Comment: after specifying "distributionMode": "PUBLIC" in skill.json it works fine now.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out this unexpected dependency. I retested it with a skill and can confirm your solution. As far as I know "distributionMode": "PRIVATE" is only applicable for Alexa for Business skills (that are not even available in most regions) and so I would expect PUBLIC to be the default.